# Updated SQL Field based on Conditions in a Related Table

Tags: sql, join, subquery

I am new to SQL and despite hours of searching, cannot figure out the SQL query to update records in my members table, based on conditions in my payments table. I'm very confused whether I use a JOIN (and if so what kind) or a Subquery?

Here's what I have so far:

```
UPDATE wp_mcra_members

SET  wp_mcra_members.dues_paid = 1

JOIN wp_mcra_payments ON wp_mcra_payments.member  = wp_mcra_members.ID 

WHERE wp_mcra_payments.year_paid = '2013' and wp_mcra_payments.reason = 'Dues';
```

I want the databased to search for any records in the Payments table that meet my conditions of being year 2013 and labeled Dues.  Then I want the Members table to update the field dues_paid based on any found records matching those conditions, where the Member ID = Payments Member

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?  Your syntax should work for SQL Server, but MySQL requires the `JOIN` before using `SET`.  The syntax varies per database.

Comment: I am using MySQL.  The solution you provided worked perfectly.  Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax you supplied looks like it would work if you are using SQL Server.  Oracle does not support `JOINs` with `UPDATE`, instead look into using `MERGE` or Gordon's answer would also work there.

Assuming however you are using MySQL, a `JOIN` in the `UPDATE` statement would probably have a better performance than using `IN`:

```
UPDATE wp_mcra_members
    JOIN wp_mcra_payments ON wp_mcra_payments.member = wp_mcra_members.ID 
SET  wp_mcra_members.dues_paid = 1
WHERE wp_mcra_payments.year_paid = '2013' 
    and wp_mcra_payments.reason = 'Dues';
```

Comment: @JMQUIG -- np, glad we could help!

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for an `update` with a `join` varies by database.  Here is generic syntax using a subquery in the `where` clause:

```
UPDATE wp_mcra_members
    SET dues_paid = 1
    where wp_mcra_members.id in (select wp_mcra_payments.member
                                 from wp_mcra_payments
                                 WHERE wp_mcra_payments.year_paid = '2013' and
                                       wp_mcra_payments.reason = 'Dues'
                                ) ;
```